# dynamically set value to select2 from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, triggers, jquery-select2

I have problem with JS Select2 dropdown.
I'm try set dynamic varibles form array to box with tags.
First tag is ok, but I can't see others.

My CODE

```
//array
var t1 = array[0];
var t2 = array[1];
var t3 = array[2];

//I see tihs varible
alert(t1 + t2 + t3);

var $exampleMulti = $(".select2_multiple").select2();
$exampleMulti.val([t1, t2, t3]).trigger("change");
```

!!! help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You can not just put a JavaScript array in a `<select>` like this. you have to create `<option>` tags and then append assign them to your `<select>`. Also `jQuery` does not have any method named `.select2()`!

Comment: thanks, I used this Js plugin Select2 https://select2.github.io/examples.html#programmatic , I want add multi value from array to .select2_multiple

Comment: So please follow the instruction in [this section](https://select2.github.io/examples.html#data-array) of the plugin examples...